# Возведение числа в степень (из книги Шилдта)

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.. какую функцию несет выражение `e--;` в примере программы ниже. Пример взят из книги Шилдта - руководство для начинающих. Программа выводит результат возведения в степень числа 2.

```
int e;
int result;

for (int i = 0; i <10; i ++) {

    result = 1;
    e = i;
    while (e > 0) {

        result *= 2;
        e --;
    }

    System.out.println("2 в степени " + i + " равно " + result);
```

если убрать строчку `e--;` то результатом вывода будет:

> 2 в степени 0 равно 1

и программа не останавливает свою работу, если не нажать стоп.

а с наличием этой строчки все работает правильно. Я никак не могу понять какую роль она играет.

Comment: смотрите на строчку `while(e > 0){`

Comment: Она уменьшает значение e на 1 каждую итерацию цикла while и обеспечивает условие выхода когда e становится 0

Comment: обеспечивает условие выхода из цикла while )) гениально ! Наконец-то дошло)  Спасибо ))

Comment: @InnaMien оформил как ответ

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция  `e--` это декремент с присвоением, короткая запись выражения

```
e = e - 1;
```

Она уменьшает значение `e` на `1` каждую итерацию цикла `while` и обеспечивает условие выхода когда `e` становится `0`